# Problems with npm, node-gyp and gulp on MAC OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, gulp, node-gyp

I've problems with installing **npm**, **node-gyp** and gulp on my MAC. I need this for a **Laravel** project. I did my research throughout the internet but I could not find a solution which was working for me. It seems like something goes wrong with the paths.

I've tried:

- installing node/npm through the website [nodejs.org](http://www.nodejs.org) and this seems to install fine. After trying with `node -v` and `npm -v` everything was accessible globally.
- installing npm via **homebrew**. Works also but doesn't install all the dependencies.

When it comes to install **gulp** and **node-gyp** everything goes wrong. I tried with `npm install -g gulp`but I could not access the application file nor globally or through the install path.

If you need more info let me know!

Thank you so much for your help!

#### UPDATE

I've followed this instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689). Everything works fine until I get to the point where I have to install npm manually through `curl -L http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`. I get an error message that the SSL certificate is not verificated. Trying with `-k`gives me an error that the file could not be found. I've also tried to download the shell script and run it manually from the terminal. In that case it seems to do something but again it causes an issue with the SSL certificates.

Comment: Isn't npm installed along with node? I'd suggest installing node via homebrew (too).

Comment: It is indeed, but as I pointed out it seems to mess up the global paths.

Comment: How does it mess up stuff? I got node installed via homebrew and it's all fine for me.

Comment: It installs fine but as soon as I try to install e.g. gulp, via npm install -g gulp, I can't get gulp working. I've also found a blogpost where it explains that installing node via homebrew causes problems with npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Installing via **homebrew** seems to make the least bit of problems. It does install everything well but as stated in the link from my original post, it does mess up the paths. In case someone needs additional packages (node-gyp, gulp), it will have to be installed via `sudo npm -g yourpackagehere`.

Answer (score 1):

To install gulp you need to use `sudo` as the `-g` flag tries to install the package to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/`.

Either do `sudo npm install -g gulp` or change the permissions of `/usr/local/` so that your user or a group its in has write access.

Comment: P.S. I installed Node.js on my Mac OS X using the .pkg from the site, everything works great